# What is the _acp-sync._tcp bonjour service for?

Tags: bonjour

When I browse my home network with a bonjour browser, I see this _acp-sync._tcp bonjour service beeing advertised by all my AirPort base stations. Can anyone give me any insights on what this is for?

Comment: Apparently acp-sync stands for Access Control Policy Synchronization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only likely reference I can find for an ACP protocol is in the man page for [natutil](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/natutil.8.html):

> natutil uses the ACP protocol to detect, configure, and extract status information from Internet gate-way gateway way devices (IGDs) (such as AirPort Base Stations) on the local network.

I doubt you'll find out much further about it without firing up a packet sniffer as the dearth of information about it is a good indicator that Apple want to keep it proprietary.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, I'd quite forgotten about that feature of Server.  And Lion now contains the natutil(8) utility in the client, with more documentation (but inaccurate control of Airport base stations).  _airport._tcp uses same port number (5009).  Sadly, the IANA registry contains very sparse information on the formats of the TXT records in either case, so we lose beyond this point. :-(